# Infinite series, convergent or divergent.

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, geometric-series

> Show whether the infinite series $$\frac{2+e^n}{3 + \pi^n}$$ is
>   convergent or divergent.

Likely to be solved using comparison, ratio test or limit of partial sum.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: For all $n \geq 1$
$$
\frac{2 + e^n}{3+\pi ^n} < \frac{2+e^n}{\pi ^n} = \frac{2}{\pi^n} + \left( \frac{e}{\pi} \right)^n
$$

Can you take it from here?